# Getting string from cell array

Tags: string, matlab, octave, cell-array

I simply want to get the string out of the cell. Every time I try to make string operations it stores the variable into a cell. I want to get the value. I tried several things but nothing works unless I convert it into a char array.

For example:

`c = {"test","test1"}
x = strcat("x",c(1,1))`

This will store a new cell in the variable x. I just want a string...

Comment: We are not omniscient. Please provide a functioning example and what you have tried already.

Comment: if you have stuff on a cell array, and you want to take one of its cells into a "normal" variable, you have to index with `{}` as in `a = your_cell_array{1}`

Comment: Please read the documentation. See [Access Data in a Cell Array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)

Comment: `c(1,1)` is a cell array, when you input cell arrays `strcat` returns cell arrays.

Comment: To expand on Daniel's comment: use `x = strcat("x",c{1,1})` to feed `strcat` with strings (not with a cell as second input) and it will produce a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want one of the cell elements as a string, you access the string using the normal cell operations:

```
c = {"test","test1"};
x = c{1};  %gets the first string
y = c{2};  %gets the second string
```

But, if you want to get all of the strings out of the cell array, you can use strvcat, which will vertically concatenate the strings into a matrix, padding with white space as needed:

```
c = {"test","test1"};
x = strvcat(c);  %returns matrix, padded with whitespace
```